# Error handling - PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I have the following powershell script that cycles through a list of hostnames and changes the DNS settings for the active interfaces:

```
$servers = Get-Content C:\users\kevin.todd\desktop\serverlist.txt 



foreach($server in $servers)

{

    Write-Host "Connect to $server..."

    $nics = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction Inquire | Where{$_.IPEnabled -eq "TRUE"}

    $newDNS = "10.100.10.81","10.100.10.82"

    foreach($nic in $nics)

    {

        Write-Host "`tExisting DNS Servers " $nic.DNSServerSearchOrder

        $x = $nic.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($newDNS)

        if($x.ReturnValue -eq 0)

        {

            Write-Host "`tSuccessfully Changed DNS Servers on " $server

        }

        else

        {

            Write-Host "`tFailed to Change DNS Servers on " $server

        }

    }

}
```

The problem is on some hosts I get the following error:

> Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x800706BA) At C:\Documents and
>   Settings\user1\desktop\changednsserver.ps1:20 char:26
>   +     $nics = Get-WmiObject <<<<  Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
>   -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction Inquire | Where{ $_.IPEnabled -eq
>   "TRUE"}
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject],
>   COMException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
>     Existing DNS Servers  You cannot call a method on a null-valued
>   expression. At C:\Documents and
>   Settings\user1\desktop\changednsserver.ps1:30 char:42
>   +         $x = $nic.SetDNSServerSearchOrder <<<< ($newDNS)
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation:
>   (SetDNSServerSearchOrder:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

And I'm asked the following question by Powershell:

> The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
>   [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
>   (default is "Y"):

I would like the script to just answer A - Yes to all and continue running the script.  The problem is it just halts the script until I manually enter "A".  How can I have it automatically answer and continue?

Answer (score 2):

Well the short answer is to not tell it to stop in the first place:

$nics = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $server ***-ErrorAction Inquire*** | Where{$_.IPEnabled -eq "TRUE"}

Try:

$nics = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $server ***-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue*** | Where{$_.IPEnabled -eq "TRUE"}

Comment: OP would have to see the error still to know what's happening. So it should be `Continue`

Comment: Sorry, my read of the question was that the OP didn't care whether the error was visible or not. If I'm mistaken on that then sure, -ErrorAction Continue would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to see where Errors occur, you have also a possibility to define an error variable using the switch
`-ErrorVariable $<variable>`

If errors occur in a foreach loop, the Error variable will be an array of error messages you can later analyze by querying the defined error variable with an array index `echo $<EVariable>[<index>]`

it would be something like `echo $MyErrorArray[0]` to get the first occurred error in that array.

An elegant way would be to have all that added to a textbox/combobox for log purposes but the coice of error handling ananalyzing is yours.